# Jamaica visa requirement for Indian citizen

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, international-travel, jamaica, mauritius

Recently I found from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens) that a visa is not required to travel to Jamaica for an Indian citizen.

Does that mean I can travel directly to Jamaica with only my passport?

Can anyone clarify why a visa is not required for Indian citizens especially to some countries like Haiti, Nepal, Bhutan, Jamaica, Mauritius, and St. Kitts? Why are these countries allowing people without any visa?

Comment: Of course, as you will be unlikely to find a direct flight from India to Jamaica, you will probably have to pass through one or more other countries for which you may need a visa.

Comment: I am curious how you would travel from India to Jamaica without an intermediate stop...

Comment: Most Schengen states (Germany is a notable exception) would be possible stopover locations for an entirely visa-free trip.

Answer (score 7):

Citizens of many countries do not require visas in many other countries. A good example of this are [US citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_US_citizens) not requiring visas in the EU and vice versa.

Specifically for Indian Citizens, we do not require visas in many countries as well. A good example of this might be countries such as Nepal, Bhutan, Mauritius etc.

Typically this is due to diplomatic relations between the countries which may or may not be influenced by a significant population of Indian diaspora living in the foreign country. Many a times this is also due to fact that the countries are quite close to each other and would like to maintain their diplomatic relations from the past or in terms of trade.

So, in short, **yes** you don't require a visa for Jamaica and this is quite common all across the world for many citizens of different countries to visit other countries.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the visa requirement for any country using the [Visa and Health](http://www.staralliance.com/en/services/visa-and-health/) page on the Star Alliance website.

Specifically for an Indian citizen visiting Jamacia, a visa is NOT required.  The results include :

> Passport required.
>   - Passports and/or passport replacing documents must be valid   for the period of intended stay.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of India.
>
> Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to   cover their stay and documents for their next destination.
>
> Warning:
>     Visitors must hold return/onward tickets

Note that the "Visa required, except ..." language used here is fairly common. In this case it means that a visa is NOT required, due to the "except" clause - even though it does specifically say "Visa required".

Answer (score 3):

Countries are completely free to decide whether a visa is needed or not and can therefore waive any requirement to have a visa unilaterally (e.g. to encourage tourism) or through an agreement (“if you let my citizens visit, I will let yours visit”) as they see fit. It's actually quite common for countries to allow (some) people to visit without securing a visa in advance. Whether they do it and for who will depend mostly on local politics.

Unfortunately, for Indian citizens, [it's only the case of a handful of countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens) but some passports allow their holders [to visit large parts of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_British_citizens).

Now, why Haiti for example would exempt Indian citizens from a visa, I don't really know but given the situation of the country, immigration is probably not very high on the agenda and the country [simply allows almost everybody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Haiti) (but not citizens from neighboring Dominican Republic and Cuba) to enter without visa. [Nepal also has a very liberal policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Nepal) and some special agreement with India.